# How to match scanner output using ICC profiles in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-profile

I'm working with people over the internet to scan and document collectible cards. We each have different scanners, so a challenge we're facing is accurately syncing the colors between them. We have each purchased an R1 color target from http://www.targets.coloraid.de/. I generated ICC profiles using the target scans and LPROF. Then I applied the color profiles to scans of identical cards using Photoshop and converted the document profiles to sRGB ICE61966-2.1. I used Photoshop's default color settings and I've tried all 4 rendering intents for conversion. Yet the colors do not match! How can I use the color profiles to sync the images?

I've zipped up the color target scans, the ICC profiles that I created, and the card scans for your reference (All images reduced to make a reasonably sized download). Zip is 2.7 MB: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x3vs968odwp73r/SO-Color-Profiles.zip

**Update 1**

It seems that the colors do match. But the histograms do not line up. So if I manually apply a curves adjustment to set the white and black points for each scanner, the documents look accurate. This confuses me, since the color targets have a white to black range on them. I'd expect a color profile would adjust the darkness and lightness of color in addition to the hue. Is there any way to resolve this?

**Update 2**

So according to joojaa, color profiles don't fix black and white values in the images. So my question then is, what can I do to correct the values using Photoshop?

Comment: no the color profile does not fix white and black points by default

Comment: Is it possible to apply a color profile such that white and black points are fixed (maybe by customizing the settings)?

Comment: depends on scanner software. But yes some devices know to specify blac/white point conpensation.

Comment: Well as I said, I'm dealing with images from multiple people. So I'd rather not impose the burden of color correction on them. I'd like to handle it on my end using Photoshop. My question now becomes: what can I do to correct the values using Photoshop?

Comment: have you tried auto levels.

Comment: I'm trying to map colors to their real world hue/saturation/brightness counterparts. Using auto levels defeats the purpose of using color targets in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16514/discussion-between-joojaa-and-skibulk).